# How to find indexes in deeply nested data structure(vectors and lists) in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I'm trying to get index route of a value from a nested data structure.

I've written some code but it does not work properly

```
(defn helper
  [val form c index]
  (loop [f form
         i index
         l 0]
    (if (seq f)
      (if (or (list? (first f)) (vector? (first f)))
        (helper val (first f) (conj c l) (inc i))
        (if (= val (first f))
          (conj c l)
          (recur (rest f) (inc i) (inc l))))
      nil)))

(defn find-indexes
  [val form c index]
  (when (seq form)
    (if-let [result (helper val form c index)]
      result
      (find-indexes val (rest form) c (inc index)))))

(defn find-index-route
  [val form]
  (find-indexes val form [] 0))
```

Current behaviour:

```
(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 ("a" :my-key))) ;=> [2 1] "Works"

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 ("a" ["b" 3 :my-key]))) ;=> [2 1 2] "Works"

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 ("a" ["b" 3 () :my-key]))) ;=> nil "Does NOT Work"

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 ("a" [] ["b" 3 :my-key]))) ;=> nil "Does NOT Work"

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [] ("a" ["b" 3 :my-key]))) ;=> [0 1 2] "It has to be [3 1 2]"
```

The thing is if the function **hits empty list or vector** before finding the value it returns **nil or 0**(just for first the level)

The behaviour I need:

```
                                          ;=> [indexes...]

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 :my-key)) ;=> [2]

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 "a" :my-key "b")) ;=> [3]

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [:my-key] "c")) ;=> [2 0]

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [:my-key]])) ;=> [2 1 0]

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [[] :my-key]])) ;=> [2 1 1]

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [4 5 6 (:my-key)]])) ;=> [2 1 3 0]

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [[]]])) ;=> nil or []
```

Comment: What is this question asking? What are "indexes route"? Why is `:my` special? What is the structure of your input? What do your expected outputs mean? As written this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @amalloy edited question, is it more clear now?

Comment: Please include the actual code from your attempt.  `...` does not convince us you actually *tried* anything yourself.

Comment: @NathanDavis I've added my actual code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defn find-index-route [x coll]
  (letfn [(path-in [y]
            (cond
              (= y x) '()
              (coll? y) (let [[failures [success & _]]
                              (->> y
                                   (map path-in)
                                   (split-with not))]
                          (when success (cons (count failures) success)))))]
    (path-in coll)))
```

Examples:

```
(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 :my-key)) ;=> [2]
=> (2)

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 "a" :my-key "b")) ;=> [3]
=> (3)

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [:my-key] "c")) ;=> [2 0]
=> (2 0)

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [:my-key]])) ;=> [2 1 0]
=> (2 1 0)

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [[] :my-key]])) ;=> [2 1 1]
=> (2 1 1)

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [4 5 6 (:my-key)]])) ;=> [2 1 3 0]
=> (2 1 3 0)

(find-index-route :my-key '(1 2 [3 [[]]])) ;=> nil or []
=> nil
```

---

**Thinking about Performance**

`split-with` scans the sequence twice, with `take-while` and `drop-while`, to produce two lazy sequences. If performance is tight, you could write a version of `drop-while` that also tells you how many items it has dropped:

```
(defn counted-drop-while [pred coll]
  (loop [takes 0, tail coll]
    (if (and (seq tail) (pred (first tail)))
      (recur (inc takes) (rest tail))
      [takes tail])))
```

It just does one scan. We can easily adapt `find-index-route` to use it:

```
(defn find-index-route [x coll]
  (letfn [(path-in [y]
            (cond
              (= y x) '()
              (coll? y) (let [[fail-count [success & _]]
                              (->> y
                                   (map path-in)
                                   (counted-drop-while not))]
                          (when success (cons fail-count success)))))]
    (path-in coll)))
```

... with identical results.

Comment: Thank you so much, it did not seem hard problem to me but it was actually I've spent too much time on it :)

Comment: @ErtuğrulÇetin I must admit I enjoyed the way that destructuring the `split-with` yields both the required index and the successfulness.

Comment: Your solution is very elegant and functional idiomatic Clojure style mine was too imperative and yeah split-with seems really cool :)

Comment: What is the reason for the `& _` in `[success & _]`? If you are discarding everything but the first, why not only catch the first with `[success]`?

Comment: @ChrisMurphy probably there is a long list coming up he wants to get the first one only

Comment: @ChrisMurphy *why not only catch the first with `[success]` ?*. I don't like  Clojure's incomplete pattern matches. It's a hint (to myself, if nobody else) that the sequence can have other items we're ignoring.

Answer (score 3):

This question seemed perfect for the Specter library, which is all about navigating and transforming nested data structures. I asked Nathan Marz about a possible solution to this problem on Clojurians yesterday - see his original answer [here](https://clojurians-log.clojureverse.org/specter/2017-08-20.html):

```
(defn find-index-route [v data]
  (let [walker (recursive-path [] p
                               (if-path sequential?
                                        [INDEXED-VALS
                                         (if-path [LAST (pred= v)]
                                                  FIRST
                                                  [(collect-one FIRST) LAST p])]))
        ret    (select-first walker data)]
    (if (vector? ret) ret [ret])))
```

Note that this returns [nil] if :my-key is not present. You could easily modify it to return nil by changing the last "if" section to this:

```
(if (or (vector? ret) (nil? ret)) ret [ret])
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a version that found **all** the route's.

```
(defn find-index-route
  "find all routes to some value"
  ([k x] (find-index-route k x []))
  ([k x p]
   (cond
     (= k x) [p]
     (coll? x) (->> (if (map? x) x (vec x))
                    (reduce-kv (fn [acc i v]
                                 (into (vec (find-index-route k v (conj p i))) acc)) []))
     :else nil)))
```

EDIT: also works on maps

```
(find-index-route :my-key '{:bar 33
                            :foo [{:my-key ("0" :my-key)}]
                            "bar" ["key" {:foo ([:my-key])}]})
;=> [["bar" 1 :foo 0 0] [:foo 0 :my-key 1]]
```

Comment: what is p? and could you show some examples that use your function?

Comment: `p` is the actual path/route.
`(= k x) [p]` returns a vector with the actual route.
`nil` means "this route is useless"

Answer (score 0):

Also I found an another solution:

```
(defn find-index-route
  [x form]
  (letfn [(get-nodes [form]
            (tree-seq coll? identity form))

          (get-tree [form]
            (rest (get-nodes form)))

          (get-level [form]
            (if (or (not (coll? form)) (not (seq form)))
              0
              (count (filter coll? (get-nodes form)))))

          (get-result [x form]
            (reduce (fn [v form]
                      (let [[idx lvl _] (last v)
                            form-lvl  (get-level form)
                            contains? ((set (get-nodes form)) x)]
                        (conj v [(if (or (not idx) (< form-lvl lvl)) 0 (+ idx 1))
                                 form-lvl
                                 contains?]))) [] (get-tree form)))

          (get-indices [x form]
            (map (fn [[idx _ _]] idx)
                 (filter
                   (fn [[_ _ contains?]] contains?) (get-result x form))))]

    (get-indices x form)))
```

Comment: @Thumbnail your solution way faster and concise but I finally solved by myself, I was thinking too imperative tho.